# How to run Visual Studio Code on Samsung Dex?

Tags: visual-studio-code, samsung-dex

Does anyone know how to run VS Code on Samsung Dex?

I've tried:
https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/writing-software-using-a-phone-e71976f1f18d

Looks like it is possible, but I don't know how. I can see vscode supports linux, does this mean that you can run vscode on Samsung Dex - Note 9 ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio Code is not natively supported on Android yet. So there is no way to natively run VSCode on Android with your Note 9 and Samsung DeX.

You do however have the following two options available:

- When using "[Linux on DeX](https://www.linuxondex.com)" then you have the option to run Visual Studio Code natively from the Linux environment on Samsung DeX, although do keep in mind that Linux on DeX is now discontinued starting Android 10.
- Remotely log into a different Linux, Windows or Mac computer and use VSCode on those computer through your phone on Samsung DeX.

Ofcourse the first option is the best. I recommend using Linux on DeX for this. Right now there isn't a native Android version of VSCode :(

Comment: Has anyone got this working with debugging .net core?
I tried and got Dex up, with VSCode, but couldn't compile .net core or run websites.

Comment: Linux is slow though. I noticed how much faster a browser, Termux and everything else is running natively in Dex. I managed to get my entire development setup running in Dex(mostly node), multiple servers etc. Only missing a good code editor now

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to go for fully functional Linux on Android.
You will require

1. Termux (Playstore)
2. VNCViewer (Playstore), bVNCViewer(recommended for tablets)
3. Andronix (Playstore), would recommend to go for premium and modded os, it would just cost you a cup of coffee. Though you can use unmodded os for free. Modded os comes with pre installed VsCode, etc useful stuffs.

Follow Andronix documentation: https://andronix.app/

Answer (score 2):

For a fully functioning visual studio code or code on a samsung tab, you can use [github codespaces](https://github.com/codespaces) in a browser tab in Dex mode, this is a paid approach but a reliable one. One other is self-hosted code instances like [code-server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server)

Answer (score 1):

As of summer 2020, there is a cloud9 style browser based VSCode service provided by Microsoft Azure:

https://online.visualstudio.com/

You can see it in action here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg0VHA_YZUI

Answer (score 0):

i didnt try that, but i think you can find a cloud coding solution, like Stackblitz that is very similar to vscode in appearance(if it's not in fact vscode), or even AWS Cloud9

Answer (score 0):

Try using a VS format with a cloud10 interfase code this will open up a rex code then type your server code in using the YZ trigger  and this will give you access.